What is a good term to indicate a "shopping session"?
I'm looking for commonly used terms for what I could describe as a "shopping session".
What I'm interested in is a variety of situations, with the main focus on a visit to the supermarket: the first thing that comes to my mind is "going for groceries", but you may also buy non-food items like personal care products, cleaning tools, etc.
But I'd like a term that also covers other kinds of shopping, including retail shops (I usually get the plain "going shopping" as a reference to buying clothes or other fashion items), commodities (hardware, home decor...), specialized food shops (bakeries, boulangeries, butcher or fish shops...) or even restaurants or fast foods.
To find another (loose) definition, I am looking for a term to describe something that results in a receipt, such that you buy a list of items, each with its own price.
I guess a term that wide does not exist, but everything that is not a verb will be a good option.
EDIT: Clarified that I am looking for a noun or an expression, not a verb.
EDIT 2: Thanks for all the suggestions - I'm getting the idea that I'm looking for a term that probably doesn't exist.
These are valid examples of what I mean:

I go to the supermarket, I buy this this and that, I pay and I leave: this is "I've gone shopping" one time;
I go to a stationery store, I buy a few things, I pay: this is another "time I've gone shopping";
I go to a hardware store, and again I buy some items: another "time I've gone shopping".

These are example of what it is not:

I and my friends have been visiting shops all afternoon ("we've gone shopping");
I'm leaving home to go to the supermarket, and maybe I'll have a walk after that if it's not too late ("I'm going for a shopping trip");
I'm browsing through stores to search for a certain item and compare prices and availability ("I'm shopping around").

Forget about the restaurants: that was a bad example, I shouldn't have mentioned it. What I'm looking for is a term for the "act of going shopping". If we were to record our shopping "sessions" (pardon the IT-sounding term), we would probably end up keeping track of our receipts, but it's not an exact mapping. It's more of an "occasion when I've gone to a shop and bought certain things".
